# Subscribe to click events from checkboxes that share a CSS class, no jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I believe in jQuery the way to do what I'm looking for is

```
$('.checkbox-class').click(handler);
```

Is it possible to do this without jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do this without jQuery?

jQuery is written in JavaScript, so it's always possible to write jQuery code in terms of plain JS.

There are two things happening in that jQuery statement:

- Select all elements with class `checkbox-class`
- Attach a callback function to be called when any of the elements are clicked

Selecting elements in JavaScript can be done with the [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method. For example:

```
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox-class');
```

Note that this returns an Array-like object with each matching element.

To add an event listener to an element, we use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). For example:

```
e.addEventListener('click', handler);
```

To put the two together, we need to iterate over each checkbox element and add the click handler.

```
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox-class');
Array.from(checkboxes).forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', handler));
```

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) allows us to use methods from the Array prototype on the Array-like collection of elements returned by querySelector[All].  The [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method iterates over each element and the inner function (using [fat-arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax) does the event binding.

Comment: `NodeList` has a [`forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) now, so we can cut out the `Array.from` middleman.

Answer (score 0):

[CodePen example.](https://codepen.io/giumagnani/pen/KZJoex)

First, get all the elements with the same class name with the [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method. Then use use a `for` loop and apply to each element the [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method to add the click event.

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox-class');

for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('checkbox checked');
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers now support `querySelector` which does what jQuery does, see this page for details.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Also you can use addEventListener to get events. See this page

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers

Comment: Since the question mentions "checkboxes" (plural) `querySelectorAll` would probably be a good idea.